# extern passing data from one instance to another of a different class

Tags: objective-c, extern

I have the following code in objective C:

class1.h:

```
...
extern NSString global;
...
```

class1.m:

```
  ...
    NSString *global;
    @implementation:
    ..
-dostuff{
    global=@"hi";
}
    ..
    @end
    ...
```

class2.m:

```
  #import "class1.h"
    ...
-printval:{
    NSlog(@"%@",global)
}
    ...
```

After I call a method in class 1, I then call a method in class 2, which attempts to print out global. However this doesn't work...am I not understanding this right?

Answer (score 0):

this isn't exactly right. The keyword `extern` is used to tell the compiler that a global (non-static) variable is declared in another module (file). So you should try something like this.

class1.h:

```
...
NSString *global = nil;
...
```

class1.m:

```
  ...
    extern NSString *global;
    @implementation:
    ..
-dostuff{
    global=@"hi";
}
    ..
    @end
    ...
```

class2.m:

```
#import "class1.h" 
...
extern NSString *global;
-printval:{
    NSlog(@"%@",global)
}
    ...
```

Comment: mugetsu: I think it would also be good to clarify, do you really need this string to be available as a global? If you just need data from Class1 instances available to Class2 instances, you should just give it an accessor, such as [a @property statement](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1), in Class1.

Comment: yes you are correct, that is a better way of solving this problem. But nevertheless, it is still important to know how extern works, so I just figured I'd explain that.

Comment: And the title specified extern :P

Comment: True. :-) But the title also specified passing data from an instance, which an extern won't do. For someone coming from a non-OOP background trying to access an ivar, an extern might seem like a logical guess. So you're totally right, but I just wanted to check.

Comment: it's cool :)
I hope the OP uses your solution, as it is a much better solution. I was just trying to help him do what he was trying to do.